# Override ToolTip Template programmatically

Tags: wpf, templates, tooltip

I want to override Tooltip Template programmatically.
The equivalent xaml code is:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My attempt:

```
 ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
 tooltip.Content = panel; // Panel with text.
 var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ToolTip));
 tooltip.Template = controlTemplate;
 // ............. -> ContentPresenter ??
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using to try and do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.Content = panel; // Panel with text.
var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(ToolTip));
controlTemplate.VisualTree = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentPresenter));
tooltip.Template = controlTemplate;
```